# DatagridView Columnas SQL server VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

Buenas Noches. Disculpen quisiera que me ayuden estoy realizando un datagridview que tiene estas columnas que yo le puesto:

- ID
- Nombres Completos
- Apellidos Completos

y en mi base de datos tengo dos tablas creadas:

La tabla Alumnos que tiene estos campos :

- IdAlumno
- Nombres
- Apellidos
- Edad
- IdCursos
- Nota

La tabla Cursos que tiene estos Campos :

- IdCursos
- Cursos

como la imagen que adjunto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero yo en mi datagrid quiero que salga con esas columnas : osea que los registros salgan como columna solo en los cursos y abajo su nota como esto :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo quisiera que me ayuden porfavor :

```
 Private Sub btnMostrar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMostrar.Click
        Dim SqlDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter("select*from alumno", SqlConnection)
        Dim DataTable As New DataTable()
        SqlDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)
        For Each DataRow As String In DataTable.Rows
            Dim n As Integer = (DataGridView1.Rows.Add)

        Next

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo desde el SQL hacer un [pivot](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx), lo cual consiste en convertir en Columnas las Filas o viceversa (unpivot).

Así quedaría:

```
SELECT a.idalumno, a.nombre, a.apellido, a.edad, a.idcursos, a.nota, c.cursos
FROM alumnos a
INNER JOIN cursos c ON a.idcursos = c.idcursos
PIVOT (SUM(a.nota) FOR c.cursos IN ([Matematica], [Comunicacion], [Religion], [Fisica]))
```

Espero que este te sirva y te de una guía.